# How to get TX/RX bytes without ifconfig?

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

Since `ifconfig` is apparently being deprecated in major Linux distributions, I thought I'd learn something about the `ip` tool that's supposed to be used instead of `ifconfig`.

And here I ran into a problem: when run on its own, `ifconfig` shows the number of bytes received/transmitted on each interface besides other info. I couldn't find a way to get this from `ip`. Is there no such function in this tool? What other built-in tools could I use for getting those stats?

Comment: You can also check out `netstat`. http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Another option is to use the /proc filesystem. The **/proc/net/dev** file contains statistics about the configured network interfaces. Each line is dedicated to one network  interface and it contains statistics for receive and transmit. The statistics include metrics such total number of received/transmittted bytes, packets, drops, errors and so on.

```
cat /proc/net/dev

    Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
     face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed

    lo:    29846937   129576     0    0    0     0          0       0 29846937   129576     0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan0:    9467393340 8027251    0    0    0     0          0       0 2559312961 5896509    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Or you can try the **netstat** command which can display all network interfaces and related statistics:

```
netstat -i

Iface   MTU Met    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
lo         65536   0   130435      0      0      0   130435      0      0      0 LRU
wlan0       1492   0  8028018      0      0      0  5897361      0      0      0 BMRU
```

Comment: `/proc/net/dev` has the cleanest format of all of the solutions IMO, accepting.

Comment: Stats showed by `cat /proc/net/dev` are for how long time ?

Comment: How do you get tx/rx from `/proc/net/dev` ?

Comment: Try to parse 3. and 11. field of the output, something like awk '/:/ { print($1,$3, $11) }' < /proc/net/dev

Comment: netstat is deprecated along with ifconfig. On Linux, not sure about other *IX varietals.

Comment: `netstat -i` cuts off interface names after the 8th char, not very usable if your system has longer interface names (which mine does). Recommend using `ss -i` instead. `ss` is the replacement to netstat. Unrelated, many flags that were used in `netstat` are supported in `ss`

Answer (score 83):

The `ip` command which is part of the the iproute2 package is the new tool.  The `link` subcommand is for managing the devices/interfaces.

If you can get the stats of an interface using `ip -s link`

```
root:~# ip -s link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    50679705   529967   0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    50679705   529967   0       0       0       0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:7d:aa:e3:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    187663757  308710386 0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    4051284587 532435117 0       0       0       0
```

Comment: While the `proc` answer is clean and lightweight, this answer is probably the closest to a "replacement" for the `ifconfig` tool because it was explicitly designed with replacement of `ifconfig` in mind.

Comment: `ip -s link show dev eth0` to show only traffic on eth0

Comment: To get this in human readable form (reporting in mb/gb/tb rather than bytes), use the `-h` flag. For instance, `ip -h -s link`.

Answer (score 62):

You can get all necessary info via proc

```
# cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
# cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_packets

# cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_packets
# cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes
```

Also you can use iptables and parse output.

**For received packets**

```
# iptables -L INPUT -n -v
```

**for transmitted packets**

```
# iptables -L OUTPUT -n -v
```

If server is a gateway, then you should also parse **FORWARD** chain

Comment: This answer is the most simple, I was able to build a script with this fairly easily. Also I use `mmwatch` (https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-blog/blob/master/2017-06-29-ssdp/mmwatch) to turn the values in to rates. However, do not use `iptables` now, it is deprecated.

Comment: to have a single command to use when checking on servers I use
 `grep . /sys/class/net/$(ip route show|awk '/default/{print $5}'|head -1)/statistics/*|grep -v ':0$'`
or - if you know the name of the nic - `grep . /sys/class/net/wlp0s20f3/statistics/*|grep -v ':0$'`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file `/sys/class/net/wlp3s0/statistics/rx_bytes` and get the rx_byes directly without calling another command, `vnstat` is also good.
Linux stores all information in files as I know, so better to find those files and get information. Finding the relevant file is the challenge.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Well done, that's correct, but note that some old kernels don't provide these files. Wish you luck, and success! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ethtool:

```
ethtool -S eth0
```

The benefit to ethtool, is you can see each rx / tx queue and how they are balanced.

I found `watch` is a great tool to update the screen using all these tools. However most of these tools display traffic as bytes or packets per second. I find it difficult to convert bytes to gigs or pps to millions of packets persecond on the fly.
Just a tip, check out Cloudflare's `mmwatch` tool. It does the same as watch, but will do the calculations automatically and display the output to the screen like watch. (Example: So you will see `1.2m/s` for 1.2 million packets per-second)

https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-blog/blob/master/2017-06-29-ssdp/mmwatch

Also, `ethtool -S eth0` gives A lot of output, I grep the following way to show receive queues and discards also with mmwatch:

```
mmwatch "ethtool -S eth0 | grep 'rx-\|discard'"
```