# See past bandwidth by process on a Linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, security

I have a [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) server (Xenial Xerus). My server statistics say that last night there was a bandwidth peak at 3+ TB, and I don't know why. I tried [SLURM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager), and it showed that I actually used that traffic:

[image]

Is there any way I can find out what caused this traffic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have anything currently installed that is monitoring and logging then you do not have any way to narrow down which process(s) were consuming bandwidth. I would recommend [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/) or [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) for overall usage statistics and [nethogs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nethogs) for narrowing down which process is using your network bandwidth.

You can install all three by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nethogs
sudo apt-get install vnstat vnstati
sudo apt-get install mrtg mrtg-contrib mrtg-ping-probe mrtg-rrd mrtgutils mrtgutils-sensors pcp-import-mrtg2pcp
```

This will install each of the programs along with their associated modules and utilities.

Comment: Ok good. Can I know how to check what process used my bandwidth? That is most important in my case!!

Comment: Great. Could you brief more on how to solve this issue? I suspect a breach in my server. It is sending out traffic, like 3TB in a day.. I have to find what is doing it and purge it.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't already have monitoring installed and configured then you have not history. You can't get the information you want.

Comment: But how slurm is able to say I used 3308 GB of data?

Comment: I guess it just keeps track of some system counters e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/533513/how-to-get-tx-rx-bytes-without-ifconfig

Comment: Oh ok fine. So what monitoring too can i install to achieve what I need in future?